# why is $f: \mathbb N^{\mathbb N} \times \mathbb N^{\mathbb N} \to \mathbb N^{\mathbb N} $ injective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have $f\colon \mathbb N^{\mathbb N} \times \mathbb N^{\mathbb N} \to \mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ such that $f$ sends the pair of sequences $a=(a_0,a_1,\dots)$ and $b=(b_0,b_1,\dots)$ to $c=(a_0,b_0,a_1,b_1,.\dots)$.

I learnt that $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ is the set of sequences of natural numbers, doesn't this include empty sequence and finite sequences? So don't we have $f(a,b)=f(b,a)=b$ if $a$ is an empty sequence?

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is made of (countably) infinite sequences of integers. Also, have you tried to show that the map $f$ is both injective and surjective ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ is the set of functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$. For each such function $f \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, we can interpret it as a sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb N}$, where $a_n = f(n)$.

But since a function must send each member of its domain to a member of the codomain, $(a_n)$ cannot be empty, and in particular must be infinite since $f(1), f(2), f(3), \dots$ must have values.

So no, $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ does not include empty and finite sequences.

This doesn't conclude that your $f$ is bijective though. You still need to confirm injectivity and surjectivity.

Comment: @kipt, the sequence $(a_n)$ can contain a finite number of different elements, for example if the function $f$ is constant, the sequence $(a_n)$ just contains only an element $c$, in fact $a_n=c$ for any $n\in\Bbb N$. In this case the sequence $(a_n)$ is equal to $(c,c,\ldots,c,\ldots)$.

Comment: @Angelo I don't disagree! Perhaps I should reword my answer. I was addressing the statement that $\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ contains finite sequences, not that $f \colon \mathbb N^\mathbb N \times \mathbb N^\mathbb N \to \mathbb N^\mathbb N$ is bijective.